# mysql now() function

Tags: mysql, date

What's the SQL way of doing this:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '$now' > time
```

Is it:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE now() > time
```

Comment: go to mysql console and check...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second example is the correct pure SQL method of doing it.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOW() > `time`
```

Although I find it more readable to reverse them, as it seems to make better logical sense to think *the value of `time` is before now`.* This really makes no difference though, and is based on my preference.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `time` < NOW()
```

There are many more native MySQL date functions you can use in your queries, [described in the MySQL documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

For example, to compare against 5 minutes ago, use [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `time` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Comment: What about say, now minus 5 mins?

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand question - first example is calculating date according to your php backend, second using mysql server's builtin function. essentialy effect is the same.

And if you ever considered, now() function in mysql is deterministic (it will replicate correctly to slaves), so even in master-slave environment both snippets of code have no difference, as long as php backend and sql server have synchronized clocks.

just to clarify: of course if your php backend and mysql clocks are not synchronized there will be differences between both snippets of code, but in normal environment this should not happen, at least be irrelevant.

Comment: Incorrect.  The first one returns the time from the webserver, the second from the database server.

Comment: just what I said, one is calculated by php backend, second by mysql server. Its safe to assume that both dates are same (or differences are <1 second and irrelevant) in most apps. Determining which date is correct (php's or mysql) is pointless - both should be equally correct and may be equally wrong - both php and mysql are NOT time servers. We don't have enough context to tell which date would be 'better'

Comment: your initial post wasn't nearly as detailed as it is now.  It was essentially saying "they're the same, it shouldn't matter which one you use"; which is not correct.

Comment: indeed, I have edited it to be more precise, thanks for pointing it out.